# Icon zip can not save file in the destination path

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

Hi all I have written the code to download the file as zip and save but I am getting an exception as `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\fileName.txt'.`. This is my code can some one help me

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
        zip.AddFile("fileName.txt");
        string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Attachments_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
        string sFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, "attachment.zip");
        File.Create(sFilePath);
        Response.BufferOutput = false;  // for large files
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + sFilePath);
        zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
        zip.AddDirectory(pathString);
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        zip.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions for the IIS Express folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `Server.MapPath` to provide absolute path to the file.

```
zip.AddFile("fileName.txt");
```

will become

```
zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath("") + "\\fileName.txt");
```